# Fast computation of square root inverse of matrix, matrix being determined from Ax=b form

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix, inverse, matrix-free

I have an equation of the form $J^Te=f$, where $e$ and $f$ are known vectors and $J$ is an unknown matrix.

How can I efficiently compute $J^T(JJ^T)^{-1/2}e$ ?

My motivation to address this problem is that, as a part of a bigger problem I need to compute matrix $J$ then compute $J^T(JJ^T)^{-1/2}e$. However, computation of matrix $J$ is expensive and $J$ results to be a large matrix, thereby the determination of product-transpose-squareroot-inverse of it is taking a lot of time. Hence, I'm planning to bypass the expensive computation of $J$ with the help some known vectors $e$ and $f$ and the relation $J^Te=f$.

Comment: Welcome to Scicomp.SE! Do you have any indication whether the quantity you are looking for can actually be computed given only $e$ and $f$? (The one equation $J^T e=f$ is not nearly enough to uniquely determine $J$.)

Comment: @ChristianClason I understand that J may not be unique. If there is a possibility, I want to look for a computation procedure which returns same $J^T(JJ^T)^{-1/2}e$ value irrespective of $J$

Comment: The point is that there might not be a unique value irrespective of $J$. (In fact, I'd rather expect so.) Maybe you could edit the question to add a bit more detail where this problem is coming from?

Comment: @ChristianClason I hope the edit helps

Comment: @user3619023: Which $J^T (JJ^T)^{-1/2} e$ do you want?  For (almost) any $e$ and $f$ and desired result $g$, you can contrive a $J$ such that $J^T(JJ^T)^{-1/2}e = g$ and $J^Te=f$.

Comment: @user3619023 Actually, it doesn't -- you are just repeating the original question in different words. Without knowing exactly where $J$, $e$ and $f$ come from, I'm afraid you're not going to get a better answer than "Sorry, using only $e$ and $f$, it is impossible to compute the quantity you are looking for."

Comment: As an example, (unless I'm mistaken) if neither $e$ or $f$ contained any zeros, then you could define $J$ to be a diagonal matrix, then $J(JJ)^{-1/2}e=e$

Answer (score 1):

The problem is wildly underdetermined. Of the infinitely many equations for $J$ of the equation $J^T e=f$ is the (rank-one) matrix
$$
  J^T = \frac{f e^T}{\|e\|^2}.
$$
For this, you have that
$$
 JJ^T = \frac{e f^Tf e^T}{\|e\|^4} = \|f\|^2 \frac{e e^T}{\|e\|^4}.
$$

Interestingly, this matrix satisfies
$$
  (JJ^T)(JJ^T) = \|f\|^4 \frac{e e^T}{\|e\|^4} \frac{e e^T}{\|e\|^4}
  = \|f\|^4 \frac{e e^T e e^T}{\|e\|^8}
  = \|f\|^4 \frac{e e^T}{\|e\|^6} = \frac{\|f\|^2}{\|e\|^2} JJ^T.
$$
This means that
$$
  (JJ^T)^{1/2}
  = \frac{\|e\|}{\|f\|} JJ^T.
$$
This allows you to compute the quantity you are interested in.

EDIT: To see how the last line follows, take the square of the left and right hand sides (i.e., multiply each side with itself) to obtain
$$
  JJ^T
  = \frac{\|e\|^2}{\|f\|^2} (JJ^T) (JJ^T).
$$
This is, up to division by the factor on both sides, the same as before.

So, how to proceed then: We know that $A := JJ^T = c ee^T$ where $c=\|f\|^2/\|e\|^4$. In other words, if you multiply $A$ by $e$, you get a multiple of $c\|e\|^2 e$ from it. Conversely, this means that applying $A^{-1}$ to this direction $e$, you get one over this multiple, i.e., $A^{-1}e=\frac{1}{c\|e\|^2}e$. (This inverse does not strictly exist -- I'm just taking the pseudo-inverse $A^\dagger$ when I write $A^{-1}$). This brings us back to the equation
$$
  (JJ^T)^{-1/2}
  = \frac{\|f\|}{\|e\|} A^{-1}
$$
and consequently
$$
  (JJ^T)^{-1/2}e
  = \frac{\|f\|}{\|e\|} A^{-1}e
  = \frac{\|f\|}{c\|e\|^2} e
  = \frac{\|f\|\|e\|^4}{\|f\|^2\|e\|^2} e
  = \frac{\|e\|^2}{\|f\|} e.
$$
With this, you get
$$
  J^T(JJ^T)^{-1/2}e
  = \frac{1}{\|f\|} fe^Te
  = \frac{\|e\|^2}{\|f\|} f.
$$

All of this said, this is just one choice for $J$. Other choices may yield different results.